# What is wrong with function returning typename list<T>::iterator?

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I have written:

```
template<class T> 
typename list<T>::iterator partition(list<T> &, list<T>::iterator, list<T>::iterator);
```

but my compiller found an error:

> error: 'std::list::iterator' is not a type

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Xeo!
Now I know - I have just forgotten "typename" words before "list..." in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 template<class T> 
 typename list<T>::iterator partition(list<T> &, typename list<T>::iterator, typename list<T>::iterator);
                                                 ^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^
```